# How can I display two colorboxes (popup windows)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using this jQuery plugin http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ to show a popup window. There is a link in the content of the first popup clicking on which triggers another small popup window. I'd like to have this second popup without closing the first one. Is it possible to achieve this without changing much in the plugin?

Comment: I came here to ask the very same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be no way to do that without significantly altering the plugin.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the chops, consider using ColorBox with the html parameter for the first popup window. In the HTML, develop your own window, eventing and handler (with Jquery). Just a thought.